# Strong differentiability in Sobolev spaces

Tags: analysis, derivatives, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

My question is: how can one prove that if $\phi\in H^{n}(a,b)$ for all positive integer $n$, then $\phi\in C^{\infty}(a,b)$?

$H^{n}(a,b)$ denotes de Sobolev space of the real interval $(a,b)$. For my purposes one can assume that $\phi(a)=\phi(b)=0$.

I understand that there is actually a stronger result: if $\phi\in H^{n+1}(a,b)$, then $\phi\in C^{n}(a,b)$ (something which I know is true for $n=0$). In other words, having $n+1$ weak derivatives, implies that the function has at least $n$ strong derivatives.

Is this true? Can anyone give me a sketch of the proofs?

Comment: Actually, you lose only $\frac12 + \epsilon$ derivatives, i.e.
$$H^{\frac12 + \epsilon}([a,b]) \subset C^0([a,b])$$
which uses the boundedness and, I think, also the compactness or at least precompactness.

Comment: If you know that $\phi\in H^{n+1}(a,b)$ implies that $\phi\in C^n (a,b)$ so, what is the problem in iterating it to get that $\phi\in C^\infty (a,b)$?

Comment: I don't know how to prove that either.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to prove that: $\phi\in H^1(a,b)$ implies $\phi\in C^0{(a,b)}$, but this follows from Theorem 8.2 of [Brezis](http://image.sciencenet.cn/olddata/kexue.com.cn/upload/blog/file/2010/12/2010127131928961750.pdf) book.